# flutter firestore how I filter data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection (Groups) inside it
fields contain information about users who joined the group,

I want to display to the user all groups he joined.

```
List groupList = [];

void getAvailableGroups() async {
    await _fireStore
        .collection('Groups')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
        groupList = value.docs;
    });
  }
```

[image: collection]

I tried to convert from map into array but it gives me array within map this is my code

```
Future createGroup() async{
    GroupRoomModel newGroup = GroupRoomModel(
        groupName: groupName.text,
        groupRoomId: uuid.v1(),
        owner: userModel.uid,
        membersList: controller.membersList,
        membersListUid: controller.membersListUid.cast() // like this
    );
}
...
```

Also I tried

```
  Future createGroupFunc() async{
    GroupRoomModel newGroup = GroupRoomModel(
        groupName: groupName.text,
        groupRoomId: uuid.v1(),
        owner: userModel.uid,
        membersList: controller.membersList,
        membersListUid: controller.membersListUid.map((e)=> e).toList()
    );
...
```

Comment: You can use where to filter your data. See https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#filtering

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: @gilorip: in that case please edit your question to show what you tried based on the documentation linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be tempting to try filtering based on something like this:

```
_fireStore
  .collection('Groups')
  .where('membersList', arrayContains: 'test@email.com')
```

This won't work though, as `arrayContains` only finds something a match when it matches a *complete* item in the array. You can't use `arrayContains` to match just a subset of an item.

The common solution is to add an additional array field to your documents with just the property you want to be able to query on. For example:

```
memberEmails: ['test@email.com', 'test@example.com']
```

With such an addition field, you can query with:

```
_fireStore
  .collection('Groups')
  .where('memberEmails', arrayContains: 'test@email.com')
```

Comment: Thank you for your helping, I saw your answer today sorry for late,  I have question how to covert map into array? I updated the question and I added more information. and thank you very much again.